# How can I make a 2-D array in C using user inputs

Tags: arrays, c

I tried to make a 2-D array given the numbers of rows and columns as the user input.

```
int main(void)
{
   int nx, ny;
   scanf_s("%d", &nx);
   scanf_s("%d", &ny);
   int array[nx][ny];
   return 0;
}
```

But VSC is telling me that I must have constants in the parenthesis [].

Is there any way I can convert 'nx' and 'ny' as constant?

Or is there any other way to declare 2-D or N-D arrays without converting their dtype?

Comment: MSVC doesn't support this, you will have to use a different compiler or dynamic allocation

Comment: @M.M Oh.... that's sad. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Will this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390179/4386427

Answer (score -1, accepted):

C99 introduced "Variable Length Arrays" (["VLAs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), but I would strongly discourage their use.
Your best bet is to use good old [malloc()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

> EXAMPLE:
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>  
> int main()
> {
>     int r = 3, c = 4; //Taking number of Rows and Columns
>     int *ptr, count = 0, i;
>     ptr = (int *)malloc((r * c) * sizeof(int)); //Dynamically Allocating Memory
>     for (i = 0; i < r * c; i++)
>     {
>         ptr[i] = i + 1; //Giving value to the pointer and simultaneously printing it.
>         printf("%d ", ptr[i]);
>         if ((i + 1) % c == 0)
>         {
>             printf("\n");
>         }
>     }
>     free(ptr);
> }
> ```

---

ADDENDUM:

MSVS might support VLAs in version 16.8 or higher: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/

Comment: why do you write `(int *)` before `malloc`. Surely this can just cause suppression of compiler warnings, for no benefit

Comment: Also this dynamically allocates a 1-D array and is mis-titled

Comment: *C99 introduced "Variable Length Arrays" ("VLAs"), but I would strongly discourage their use.*  That's misguided - at best.  Despite Microsoft's protestations and insistence on remaining stuck in the last century, VLAs are extremely useful and no more "dangerous" to memory than any other C construct.  See [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for just one example of how powerful and perfectly safe VLAs can be.

Comment: In the page you linked they say: *"Astute readers will note that VLAs are also not supported. Variable length arrays are generally less efficient than comparable fixed sized arrays, and generally inefficient compared to equivalent malloc(), when safely and securely implemented. VLAs provide attack vectors comparable to those of the infamous gets() — deprecated and destined to removal — for opportunities of “shifting the stack” and other exploits. For these reasons **we intend not to support VLAs as an optional feature in C11**."*. That doesn't really sounds like MSVC "might" support VLAs...

Answer (score 1):

This is would be a way of doing it:

```
int main(void)
{
   int nx=0, ny=0;#intialize some random values to the variable
   scanf_s("%d", &nx);
   scanf_s("%d", &ny);
   int array[nx][ny];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @elitalon How is this a comment? Although this answer is low-quality, an answer being code-only by itself is not a reason to vote to delete. If any action should be taken, it is downvoting.

Comment: Yes I agree that

Answer (score 0):

You should use **malloc** or for educational purposes declare MAX size matrix and work only within nx-ny region

```cpp
#define MAX 1000
int main(void)
{
   int nx, ny;
   int array[MAX][MAX];
   scanf_s("%d", &nx);
   scanf_s("%d", &ny);
   if(nx > MAX || ny > MAX) return 1; // valid range check 
   // work with array
   return 0;
}
```